# Pop works only once in specific function

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I implemented stack as linked list and I wanted to make function which tells if brackets are in good order for example : (()) is good ())( is bad . Logic of function isn't good right now but I don't know why pop() works only once.Here is my code(stog is stack and sljedeci is next):

```
struct stog {
    int x;
    stog *sljedeci;
};

typedef struct stog stog;

stog *top;
char pop() {
    stog *temp;
    temp = (stog*)malloc(sizeof(stog));
    temp = top;
    char n = temp->x;
    top = temp->sljedeci;
    top->x = temp->sljedeci->x;
    free(temp);
    return n;
}



void init() {
    top = NULL;
}

void push(char x) {
        stog *temp;
        temp=(stog*)malloc(sizeof(stog));
        temp->x = x;
        temp->sljedeci = top;
        top = temp;
    }

 void Brackets(const char* msg) {
    char z;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(msg); i++) {
        if (msg[i] == '(') {
            push('(');
        }
        if (msg[i]==')'){
            z = pop();
            printf("Bad\n");    
        }       
    }
}

int main() {

    const char* msg = "(())";
    init(); 
    Brackets(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

Bad

It should be:

Bad
Bad

EDIT: Added init() and push() functions

Comment: You are immediately leaking memory after the `malloc` in `pop`.

Comment: @Aplexas The function pop does not make sense in whole.

Comment: You mean I don't need top->x = temp->sljedeci->x; ?

Comment: @Aplexas no it does not make any sense at all

Comment: Read [ask].  `init()`, `push()` and `pop()` are all co-dependent on each others proper behaviors, you should post all of them.  What you have there is not an [mcve]

Comment: I don't get it why it does not make any sense because I copy pasted it from website. Can you give me pop() that make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `pop` doesn't make sense:

```
top->x = temp->sljedeci->x;
```

In the prior line, you assign `temp->sljedeci` to `top`.  So the `x` member referenced here is actually the same one on both sides, so assuming both `top` and  `temp->sljedeci` are not null it does nothing.  If either one is NULL, you invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you derefrence a null pointer.  So get rid of this line.

You also have a memory leak here in `pop`:

```
temp = (stog*)malloc(sizeof(stog));
temp = top;
```

You allocate memory and assign its address to `temp`, but then you immediately overwrite that address with the value of `top`.

There's no need to allocate more memory here, so remove the `malloc` call.

Answer (score -1):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

I am doing your assignment the first time in my life.:)

For starters always use English words for identifiers. Otherwise a program text can be unreadable.

It is unclear why the data member `x` has the type `int` instead of `char` though the stack deals with characters of a string.

```
struct stog {
    int x;
    stog *sljedeci;
};
```

You did not show all your stack implementation nevertheless for example the function `pop` is invalid. It produces a memory leak.

At first you allocated memory and its address assigned to the pointer `temp` and at once in the next line you reassigned the pointer. So the allocated memory will not be freed.

```
temp = (stog*)malloc(sizeof(stog));
temp = top;
```

This statement

```
top->x = temp->sljedeci->x;
```

can invoke undefined behavior if `top` is equal to `NULL`.

Also in the function `Brackets` this if statement

```
    if (msg[i]==')'){
        z = pop();
        printf("Bad\n");    
    }
```

does not make sense. The function will always output `"Bad"` as soon as the character `')'` is encountered.

Here is a solution I have done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    char c;
    struct stack *next;
};

char * top( struct stack **stack )
{
    return *stack == NULL ? NULL : &( *stack )->c;
}

int push( struct stack **stack, char c )
{
    struct stack *current = malloc( sizeof( struct stack ) );
    int success = current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        current->c = c;
        current->next = *stack;

        *stack = current;
    }

    return success;
}

void pop( struct stack **stack )
{
    if ( *stack )
    {
        struct stack *current = *stack;
        *stack = ( *stack )->next;

        free( current );
    }
}

int empty( struct stack **stack )
{
    return *stack == NULL;
}

void clear( struct stack **stack )
{
    while ( *stack ) pop( stack );
}

int bracket_balance( const char *s )
{
    struct stack *stack = NULL;

    int balanced = 1;

    for ( ; *s && balanced; ++s )
    {
        if ( *s == '(' )
        {
            push( &stack, *s );
        }
        else if ( *s == ')' )
        {
            if ( ( balanced = !empty( &stack ) && *top( &stack ) == '(' ) )
            {
                pop( &stack );
            }
        }
    }

    balanced = balanced && empty( &stack );

    clear( &stack );

    return balanced;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char * s[] = 
    {
        "", "(", ")", "()", ")(", "( ( ) )", "( )( )", "( ) ) (", "Hello"
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++ )
    {
        if ( bracket_balance( s[i] ) )
        {
            printf( "\"%s\" has balanced brackets\n", s[i] );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\"%s\" does not have balanced brackets\n", s[i] );
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"" has balanced brackets
"(" does not have balanced brackets
")" does not have balanced brackets
"()" has balanced brackets
")(" does not have balanced brackets
"( ( ) )" has balanced brackets
"( )( )" has balanced brackets
"( ) ) (" does not have balanced brackets
"Hello" has balanced brackets
```